# Removing values from an array

Tags: c, arrays

Is there any simple way to remove values from an array, and then move all the other values up into their positions, i.e. a bit like bit shifting?

For instance let's say I have an array

```
a[5] = {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05};
```

and I would like to remove the first two values and shift the rest so that the array then becomes:

```
a[5]= {0x03,0x04,0x05,0x00,0x00};
```

Is there any easy way to do this without having to create a new array and use a for loop to transfer all the values after `a[1]`?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: it looks like `C` to me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what language do you use, but general idea might be this

```
for(i=0; i<(5-2); i++){
    a[i] = a[i+2];
}
a[3] = a[4] = 0;
```

So you don't need a copy of array, you can just shift values in existing one.

Comment: `do this without having to create a new array and use a for loop to transfer all`

Comment: Ok yeah, that's what I kind of figured I would have to do. I was just wondering if there might be a way of doing it without a for loop.